# What Damage may Accompany a Broken Axle

Tags: honda, suspension, axle, odyssey

I was looking at buying a [98 Honda Shuttle](http://www.cars-data.com/en/honda-shuttle-2.3i-es-specs/17172) with a broken right side axle, and was wondering what other damage I should keep my eyes open for which might normally be seen together with a broken axle.

Comment: Can you expound on "broken"? Is the CVJ gone out, or is it *physically* snapped in two? Just curious as to the exact damage of the axle itself. Did the broken axle occur while it was being driven? If so, at what speed? Any other damage assessment you can provide?

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I spoke with the guy and he's clueless.  He said he was just driving around, went into a normal turn and it broke, whatever that means.  It's currently in a shop, but they can't find a replacement part, even from a wreaking yard and that's why he's considering selling it.  Apparently they told him they could try and jerry rig one from other model to try and make it work, which doesn't sound like such a great idea to me.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I think the best answer would just say what to look for if it's just the CV joint that's broken, and what to look for if it's a snapped axle / half shaft.

Comment: I don't really have a *good* answer for you. I'm not intimately familiar with these vans. If it did break, the driver most likely started pressing the gas to get the vehicle going. If it broke near the wheel side, this means more flailing around of the axle shaft. If it broke near the tranny side, the axle shaft is still flailing around, but only at the speed of the vehicle, so I think less damage would be possible. I don't know if the alternator is on the back side of the engine or not, so look around that and the exhaust (though I think that comes off the front of the engine).